# Prevent the variable's value from being written to the `body' of the page

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

When we write the code below in the Firefox web browser bookmark, the result `3` is written to the `body` of the current page:

```
javascript:
var x = 2;
x += 1;
```

To avoid this, it is possible to add `var` before a new variable called `y` that takes the value of `x`:

```
javascript:
var x = 2;
var y = x += 1;
```

My code has dozens of variables and it wouldn't be practical to have to create other variables just to avoid the problem.

How can I prevent variable values from being written to the `document.body` of the page?

Comment: Consider writing a userscript instead, they don't have that problem and are far more maintainable

Comment: In what way are the variables being added to the body of the document? You're just creating new variables that are given a new memory allocation.

Comment: The standard bookmarklet pattern is an IIFE and the `void` operator. If the expression doesn't return anything, it won't get written to the page.

Comment: @Bergi Understand. Very good!